# JavaScript: How to object push strings between characters?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, object, html-table

I'm trying to scrape data off a website which looks like this. It has 4 lines of information within a single td and I need help scraping I want the end result to look like this in the JSON file:

```
{
 "mainTitle" : "Main Title"
 "subTitle" : "Sub Title here"
 "address1" : "Address Part One"
 "address2" : "Address Part Two"
 "postalCode" : "666666"
 "telNo" : "12345678"
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="contentpage">
  <table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>Main Title</tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <strong>Sub Title here</strong>
          <br>
          "Address Part One"
          <br>
          "Address Part Two"
          <br>
          "666666"
          <br>
          "Tel No: 12345678"
        </td>
      </tr>  
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

So far I've only been able to scrap the main title and the sub title, my JavaScript:

```
function parseInfo ($) {
  const result = {}
  const enterRow = $('.contentpage > table').first().find('tr)

  result.mainTitle = enterRow.eq(0).find('td').text().trim()
  result.subTitle = enterRow.eq(1).find('td > strong').text().trim()

  return result
}
```

Comment: Add an ID to each element you would like to grab, then call the element by its ID and grab its innerHTML. If you would like an example please let me know.

Comment: The HTML that I'm trying to scrape from isn't mine, it's a public website. It's literally formatted in that way that I've written above.

Comment: Perhaps you should grab the entire `td` that includes the subtitle (not just the `strong`) and then perform string manipulations to retrieve the rest of the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get those values by splitting text with new line character.

```
function parseInfo () {
  const result = {};
  const enterRow = $('.contentpage > table').first().find('tr');
  result.mainTitle = enterRow.eq(0).text().trim();
  result.subTitle = enterRow.eq(1).find('td > strong').text().trim();
  let elements = enterRow.eq(1).find('td').text().trim().split('\n');
  let filteredElements = elements.filter(val => val.replace(/\s/g, '').length).map(val => val.trim());
  result.addressOne = filteredElements[1];
  result.addressTwo = filteredElements[2];
  result.addressCode = filteredElements[3];
  result.telNumber = filteredElements[4];
  return result;
}
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/01zmmgy5/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to split the TD, like this

```
var row_items = enterRow.split("<br>")
```

The resoult is an array.
After that all you need is to clean row items in a cycle, remove strong, double quotes.

```
for (var i = 0; i < row_items.length; i++) {
    row_items[i] = row_items[i].replace("<strong>", "").replace("</strong>", "").replace(/"/g, "")
}
```

And finally you can make the JSON like

```
result = {}
result["mainTitle"] = row_items[0]
result["subTitle"] = row_items[1]
...
```